# How to use JS in chrome extension html file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to run some JS code in a html file located in my extension's directory `chrome-extension://<my_extension_id>/notice.html`

I have tried using content scripts to inject the JS, 1st I tried the programmatically route by using chrome.tabs.executeScript. After that didn't work I tried to use the manifest to do it which also failed   .

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Shield",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Shield",
    "homepage_url": "https://example.com",
    "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

notice.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>this page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>test page!!!</h1>
        <p id="ref_test"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

notice.js:

```
    alert("notice js injected");
```

I would like to run the content script or some how run JS (notice.js) on the url `chrome-extension://<my_extension_id>/notice.html`, However it normally just does not inject

Comment: Add `<script src="notice.js"></script>` before `</body>` in notice.html

Comment: ...and you also probably don't need background.js at all.